# I Want to know JSON Parsing Steps.

Tags: json, nsurl, objective-c-runtime

[enter link description here](http://quadrobay.co.in/eduapps_api/eduapps/public/api/eduapps/state-list?token=24462a501a5aa6ca239d1ade0fc90c9c)

please parse this link and result in table view.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2010

1. Tools->Extention Manager---Download Nuget Package Manager
2. Reload Visual Studio new project
3. Right click on project and click on NuGet Package Manager
4. Search by Newtonsoft and Install Newtonsoft Msgpack

using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

```
        string jsonD = @"{  
        'FirstName':'Mahabub',  
        'LastName':'Zaman'  
        }";
        var result = JObject.Parse(jsonD);

        Console.Write(result["FirstName"]);
        Console.Write(result["LastName"]);

        Console.ReadLine();
```